# How to select all the options of a multiselect, Order should not vary

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select all the options of a multiselect box in java script?

Comment: `$(select option).prop('selected',true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
$('#your_selectbox_id').find('option').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Comment: Really great @Vaidehi Hirani and its my first experience on stackoverflow.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `each` to loop the selected items and save the values in a array

```
var selectedVal =[];
$('select').find('option:selected').each(function(){
selectedVal.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: why put in array?when you set selected to all child of select?

Comment: let the options be selected or not selected, all the options should come in the same order one by one from top to bottom.

Comment: the question is vague at best,i select the values of the selected option and save them in a array for future use

Comment: but I want all the available options top to bottom one by one .. Its very clear @madalin ivascu

Comment: then you remove the `:selected` atribute from option `$('select').find('option').each....`

Comment: Yes @madalin ivascu you are right...Thats what the answer is.

Answer (score 0):

First select all options that are selected using

```
jQuery('select#mySelect option');//mySelect is id of your multiple selectbox
```

Then loop through using .each() and select each option :

```
jQuery('select#mySelect option').each(function(index){
   console.info($(this).val() );//gets the value attribute if you have value attribute assigned to options
   console.info($(this).text() );//gets the text of each option while looping

   $(this).prop('selected',true);//this makes each option selected
});
```